# How to compute similarities between arrays?

Tags: python, similarity, hierarchical-clustering, scipy-spatial

I am trying to compute similarity between two samples.
The python functions `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` and
`scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` return results that I am not satisfied with. For example:

- In the following I would have expected 0.0%, because the two samples do not have identical samples.

  ```
   tt1 = [1, 16, 4, 21]
   tt2 = [5, 17, 3, 22]

   from scipy import spatial
   res = 1-spatial.distance.cosine(tt1, tt2)
   print(res)
   0.9893593529663931
  ```
- I would have expected 0.25% of similarity because only a single sample, the first one (1), in both arrays are the same.

  ```
   tt1 = [1, 16, 4, 21]
   tt2 = [1, 17, 3, 22]

   from scipy import spatial
   res = 1-spatial.distance.cosine(tt1, tt2)
   print(res)
   0.9990578001169402
  ```
- In the same way we have the following where I would expect 0.5% was expected. Two identical samples (1 and 16)

  ```
   tt1 = [1, 16, 4, 21]
   tt2 = [1, 16, 3, 22]
   res = 0.9989359418266097
  ```
- Here 0.75% was expected. Three identical samples (1, 16 and 4)

  ```
   tt1 = [1, 16, 4, 21]
   tt2 = [1, 16, 4, 22]
   res = 0.9997474232272052
  ```

Is there a way in python to achieve those expected results ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what the function computes. By your description you want to compute the misclassfication error / accuracy. However, the function receives two samples u,v and computes the cosine distance between them. In your first examples:

```
tt1 = [1, 16, 4, 21]
tt2 = [5, 17, 3, 22]
```

then u=tt1 and v=tt2. The different values of the two arrays are the coordinates in the vector space these samples are in (here a 4 dimensional space) - and not different samples. Refer to [function documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) and specifically to the examples at the bottom.

If each coordinate in these arrays represent a **different** sample then:

- If order matters: (consider working with numpy arrays to begin with)

  ```
  np.mean(np.array(tt1) == np.array(tt2))
  ```
- If order does not matter:

  ```
   len(np.intersect1d(np.array(tt1), np.array(tt2))) / len(tt1)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Those *vectors* are quite close together geometrically. The cosine similarity doesn't just measure whether elements are the same but how different they are.

It looks like you just want an element wise match rate?

```
sum([t1 == t2 for t1, t2 in zip(tt1, tt2)]) / len(tt1)
# or
np.equal(tt1, tt2).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `numpy.intersect1d` as explained in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html)

here is an example of how I would do it with example 4#

```
import numpy as np 
tt1 = [1, 16, 4, 21]
tt2 = [1, 16, 4, 22]
res = len(np.intersect1d(tt1, tt2)) / ((len(tt1)+len(tt2))/2)
print(res)
```